# Query to test package running in prod in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration

I want to test whether a package is being run/used since last 3 months in prod from Database end. Is there a process to check the same through any SQL query or any other way in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your AWR retention policy set long enough (3 months), you could search the ASH data for the sqlid of the procedure.